# WIX: Run batch file based on checkbox value with admin right

Tags: batch, windows-installer

I created a installer using WIX.
However, after installing the software, I have a checkbox asking the user whether to run a batch file or not. If the user check the checkbox, the batch file will run.

The batch file needs to be ran as admin right. 
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Tried using `runas`?

Comment: tried but doesn't seems to work

Comment: I tried using "runas /profile /user:administrator cmd /c BachFile,bat"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late...
But in order to get a batch file to run as an admin you need to create a shortcut to that file, go to the properties, go to advanced, select run as administrator. I use this constantly on scripts that do multiple installations etc.